# How to redirect 301 within subdomain?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I have 2 campaigns at

- `competition.example.com/option_1`
- `competition.example.com/option_2`

option_1 and optino_2 are in separate folders which are in root folder. Each file and root has its own .htaccess.
Content of:
[.htaccess](http://melichar.sk/Example-301/option_1.txt) of option_1
[.htaccess](http://melichar.sk/Example-301/root.txt) of root
How and where (which .htaccess) can I 301 redirect from `competition.example.com/option_1` to `competition.example.com/option_2`?

Comment: Where is the `competition` subdomain located on the filesystem? ...In a subdirectory called `competition`, off the document root? Do you have other .htaccess files already on your system?

Comment: In document root I have the 2 files (option_1 and option_2)

Comment: "option_1 and optino_2 are in separate filies which are in root file. Each file and root has its own .htaccess." - Do you mean, "option_1 and option_2 are separate folders in the root. Each folder and root has its own .htaccess file"?

Comment: Yes, 2 x folder in the root. Each folder and rood has its own .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .htaccess file where `competition.example.com` points to on the filesystem, you can use a mod_alias `Redirect`:

```
Redirect 301 /option_1 /option_2
```

This assumes you don't have any existing mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) redirects that might conflict.

Note that .htaccess files *inherit* along the filesystem path (regardless of whether you are using subdomains or not). So if the `competition` subdomain actually points to a `/competition` subdirectory off the main domain's document root, then the .htaccess file in the parent directory (the main domain's document root) will be processed second.

However, by default, mod_rewrite directives are *not* inherited (mod_rewrite is different to other modules in this respect). So directives in the child (subdirectory) .htaccess file will completely override the parent.

---

**UPDATE:** Since you are using mod_rewrite throughout your root .htaccess file you should change the above (mod_alias) `Redirect` to use mod_rewrite as well. mod_rewrite will execute before mod_alias, regardless of the order of directives in .htaccess, so it's quite possible there is a conflict.

At the very top of your root .htaccess file (which I assume is the root of subdomain), try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^option_1(.*)$ /option_2$1 [R=302,L]
```

This assumes you don't have *files* that start "option_1".

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK. 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so can make testing problematic. For this reason you need to make sure your browser cache is emptied before testing.

Comment: just to be sure. Its should not be like: `Redirect 301 /option_1 competition.example.com/option_2` but just like `Redirect 301 /option_1 /option_2`?

Comment: I tried both methods and I did it in root .htaccess and also in .htaccess which is in folder option_1. Non is working.

Comment: `Redirect 301 /option_1 /option_2` is OK on Apache 2.2.6+. Note that if you specify the domain you _must_ specify a complete absolute URL eg. `http://competition.example.com/option_2`. What does "not working" mean - does it do anything? Note that 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so if you have previously tested other (erroneous) redirects then you will need to repeatedly clear your browser cache. So, these are "folders", not "files" as you stated in your comment above? Is .htaccess enabled on your server? Do you have other .htaccess files (anywhere)?

Comment: Note that `example.com` also applies if it is on the same filesystem.

Comment: Im back. Im sorry, its a folder. I have .htaccess in folders: option_1, option_2 and also in the root. By the "its not working" I mean, I dont see redirection even I use different browser.

Comment: If you have existing .htaccess files in `/option_1` and the root then you should add these to your question since there might be a conflict.

Comment: I have edited question. Do you know where can be the prob?

Comment: You need to add the _contents_ of these .htaccess files to your question.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a mod_rewrite solution (since you are already using mod_rewrite thoughout your root .htaccess file).